# Error publishing message from PostgreSQL to RabbitMQ using amqp extension - login failed on broker 1

Tags: postgresql, docker, rabbitmq, amqp, postgresql-11

I am trying to publish a message from PostgreSQL to RabbitMQ (both running on Docker)

```
SELECT amqp.publish(1, 'amqp.direct', 'EMAIL', 'message');
```

but it returns `false` and Warning message:

> WARNING:  amqp[*my_host_address:my_port*] login failed on broker 1

Update:
There is error in RabbitMQ Docker container logs:

> failed to negotiate connection parameters: negotiated channel_max = 0
>   (no limit) is higher than the maximum allowed value (2047)

The broker parameters in `amqp.broker` table - host, port, virtual host, username, password are defined correctly.
It is possible to publish messages from my computers console to RabbitMQ using Curl and the same connection parameters, and they are added in message queue.

Answer (score 0):

There were two possible solutions:

1. add environment variable in RabbitMQ portainer stack:

```
    RABBITMQ_SERVER_ADDITIONAL_ERL_ARGS: '-rabbit channel_max 0'
```

2. Fix `src/librabbitmq/amqp_socket.c`

   https://github.com/omniti-labs/pg_amqp/issues/23